# How to create a SOAP Request like this in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am pretty new in the **WebServices** interrogation using Java and I have the following problem.

I have a web service that provide to me a **getConfigSettings()** method that, by its response, say to me some informations including whether a user is enabled or not on a certain service (it say if the couple **username** and **password** is correct and if the user can log into the system).

In particular I have the following **REQUEST** of the **getConfigSettings()** method:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:getConfigSettings>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:login>name.surname</tem:login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:password>rightPawssword</tem:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:ipAddress>144.44.55.4</tem:ipAddress>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:clientVersion>1</tem:clientVersion>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:lastUpdateTime>2</tem:lastUpdateTime>
      </tem:getConfigSettings>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the webservice **RESPONSE** in case the couple **username** and **password** is correct and the user can log into the system:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <getConfigSettingsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <getConfigSettingsResult>
            <![CDATA[
                <root>
                    <status>
                        <id>0</id>
                        <message></message>
                    </status>
                    <drivers>
                        <drive id="tokenId 11">
                          <shared-secret>Shared 11</shared-secret>
                          <encoding>false</encoding>
                          <compression />
                        </drive>
                        <drive id="tokenId 2 ">
                          <shared-secret>Shared 2  </shared-secret>
                          <encoding>false</encoding>
                          <compression>false</compression>
                        </drive>
                    </drivers>
                </root>
            ]]>
        </getConfigSettingsResult>
      </getConfigSettingsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In this response the important section is:

```
<status>
    <id>0</id>
    <message></message>
</status>
```

because `<id>0</id>` means that the user can log into the system

On the contrary if the couple **username** and **password** is **incorrect** I will obtain the following **RESPONSE**:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <getConfigSettingsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <getConfigSettingsResult><![CDATA[<root>
                        <status>
                            <id>-1</id>
                            <message>Login or password incorrect</message>
                        </status>
                        </root>]]></getConfigSettingsResult>
      </getConfigSettingsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see in this case I have that `<id>-1</id>` (that represent a situation of error) and in the message tag it specify the type of error occurred.

Ok, now I have to create a Java method that call this **getConfigSettings()** method passing to it the requested 5 parameters: **login**, **password**, **ipAddress**, **clientVersion** and **lastUpdateTime** (also if at this stage the only important parameters are **login** and **password**, the others can be whatever...)

And now I have no idea about how do it.

In my project there is another method that call another request report of the same web services that is:

```
public String getVersion() {
    java.net.URL url = null;
    java.net.URLConnection conn = null;

    java.io.BufferedReader rd = null;
    String soapResponse = "";

    String risultato = "";

    // SOAP ENVELOP for the request:
    String soapRequest;
    soapRequest = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" + "<soapenv:Header/>" + "<soapenv:Body> " + "<tem:getVersion/>" + "</soapenv:Body>" + "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    try {

        // Try to open a connection
        url = new java.net.URL(_webServiceUrl);
        conn = url.openConnection();

        // Set the necessary header fields
        conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/getVersion");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send the request:
        java.io.OutputStreamWriter wr = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(soapRequest);
        wr.flush();
        // Read the response
        rd = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        // Put the entire response into the soapResponse variable:
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            soapResponse = soapResponse + line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        }

        rd.close();

        // PERFORM SOME ELABORATION ON THE RESPONSE
        ..........................................
                    ..........................................
        ..........................................
                    ..........................................
                    return risultato;
}
```

Looking at this working method it seems to me that do something like that:

1. It create a String object that contain the **SOAP Envelop** for my request.
2. Try to connect to my WebService.
3. Then **Set the necessary header fields** (and this is not clear for me, what exactly mean? and what is **tempuri**?), what exactly do the following lines:

   ```
       conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/getVersion");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
       conn.setDoOutput(true);
   ```
4. Send my prepared request to the WebService
5. Obtain the response and put it into my **String soapResponse** variable

This is what I want to obtain creating the other **authentication()** method, I have to create the **SOAP Envelop** using the previous parameters, send it to the webservice and obtain the SOAP response.

I think that my main problem is how to create the right **String soapRequest** object that use the parameter to do that.

Comment: If you dispose of the WSDL, you should generate your soap client using wsimport. Your example of calling webservice is pretty used for RESTful webservices (combined with JAXB). With SOAP it should be easier. Have a look. There is one example : http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/